# Is it possible for docker-compose to access env and network during build?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to access ENV variables and other containers via network during build time, but it does not seem to work for some reason.

I can access the network and ENV variables in the CMD, but not in the RUN.

For ENV, I can add `ENV MYENV good1` and then RUN will see it, or use args. But I'd prefer not to do that as I want to pass database passwords through it.

For network, I'd prefer not to access my home network and work with the docker network.

It seems like it builds the container before putting anything up, I'd like it to wait on building until the network is up. And I am not sure why ENV variables isn't working.

Here is a minimal example that prints the ENV and pings the network in both RUN and CMD to show the issue:
`docker-compose up --build`

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  app:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: test.Dockerfile
      args:
        CACHE_BUST: 1
    environment:
      - MYENV=good1
    links:
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - redis
    networks:
      back-net: {}
  redis:
    image: "redis:bullseye"
    networks:
      back-net: {}
networks:
  back-net:
    driver: bridge
```

**test.Dockerfile**

```
FROM debian:bullseye-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install iputils-ping

RUN echo $CACHEBUST && echo "ENV " && echo $MYENV && echo "RUN HOSTS:" && cat /etc/hosts && echo "RUN PING:" && ping -c 2 redis; exit 0

CMD echo "ENV " && echo $MYENV && echo "CMD HOSTS:" && cat /etc/hosts && echo "CMD PING:" && ping -c 2 redis
```

Comment: The workflow you describe in the text is correct: the image is built before anything in the `docker-compose.yml` is necessarily running, it's not attached to the Compose network and so can't connect to other containers, and it doesn't see `environment:` variables (only `build: { args: }`; remember to use a Dockerfile `ARG` declaration too).  If you change, say, the Redis hostname, you should be able to run your container without rebuilding the image.

Comment: @DavidMaze - But the issue with ARGs is that anything you pass in it is public. If I set a redis hostname,  would it be accessible during build time though?

Comment: Your Redis isn't available during build time at all.  `ENV` values that are built into the image are _also_ public (`docker inspect the-image` will show them).  Do you need to do some additional work at container startup time, maybe via an entrypoint wrapper script?